# Finding a maximum value in a file

Tags: python

I'm in a first year CompSci class and learning Python, so bear with me here. The assignment is to open a file using Python, read it, and find the maximum value in that file without using any built in functions or concepts we haven't discussed in class. I can read through the file and get the values, but my issue is that my code will consider the value "30" to instead be "3" and "0" instead of thirty. This is what I have so far:

```
def maxValueInFile(fileName):
    inputFile = open(fileName, "r")
    currentMax = int(0)
    for value in inputFile.read():
        if value.isdigit():
            value = int(value)
            if value > currentMax:
                currentMax = value
    inputFile.close()
    return currentMax
```

When I run the file, it won't return a number higher than 9, presumably becaus

Comment: Can you show an example of what is in your file? Can you please add it to your question, then we should be able to help you :)

Comment: The file looks like this

```
10

5

16

19

2554

9

7674

76483

877

736

7546

56900
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Please [edit] the question to include some sample input.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do too much in this piece of your code (which I'll comment so you can see where it's going wrong):

```
# inputFile.read() returns something like "30\n40\n50"
for value in inputFile.read():  
    # now value is something like "3" or "0"   
    if value.isdigit():
        value = int(value)
        # and now it's 3 or 0
```

There's no benefit to splitting the string up into digits -- so don't do that.  :)

```
currentMax = 0
for line in inputFile.readLine():
    value = int(line)
    if value > currentMax:
        currentMax = value
```

Note that this code will raise a `ValueError` exception if `line` isn't convertible to an `int`!

A couple of style notes (which I've applied to the code above):

- You don't need to say `int(0)` because `0` is already an `int` all on its own.
- When you're converting types, it's better to assign a new variable to the new type (when you start using static type checking, this is required, so it's a good habit to get into).  In the code above I called the line of text we read from the file `line` to help me remember that it's a line of text (i.e. a `str`), and then I name the numeric value `value` to help me remember that that's the actual number that I can use in a comparison (i.e. an `int`).

Comment: `for line in inputFile.read()` should be `for line in inputFile`, no?

Comment: `readLine`? That doesn't exist in Python. Maybe you're thinking of another language.

Answer (score 0):

`inputFile.read()` returns a string, which gets broken into characters when you iterate over it. Assuming your input file has each value on a separate line, you want `inputFile.read().splitlines()`.

---

However, here's how I'd write it, with notes:

```
def maxValueInFile(fileName):
    currentMax = 0
    with open(fileName) as inputFile:  # Avoid manually opening and closing files
        for line in inputFile:  # Avoid reading the whole file
            # If we can assume the file only contains numbers,
            # we can skip the ".isdigit" check.
            value = int(line)  # "int()" doesn't care about whitespace (newline)
            if value > currentMax:
                currentMax = value
    return currentMax
```

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense, thank you. We've only gone over the one way to open files in class; I wasn't aware there were more options. I've got everything working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read digit by digit, you can build up the real numbers by continously multiplying the temporary result by 10, and then adding the value of the last digit read.

```
def maxValueInFile(fileName):
    inputFile = open(fileName, "r")
    currentMax = int(0)
    number = 0
    for value in inputFile.read():
        if value.isdigit():  # again found a digit
            number = number * 10 + int(value)
        else:   # found a non-digit
            if number > currentMax:
                currentMax = number
            number = 0
    if number > currentMax:  # in case the for-loop ended with a digit, the last number still needs to be tested
        currentMax = number
    inputFile.close()
    return currentMax
```